# Display date of birth based on nric number in Angular 8

Tags: angular

Hye..I want to display the date of birth in format 'dd/MM/YY' when user entered identification number which can be determined at the first 6 numbers in nric number (XXXXXX-XX-XXXX)..Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: I think you  should create custom  pipe, where you will split  first 6 numbers and pass them to `DatePipe`

Comment: It would be great if you can add a stackblitz link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,you can make a custom `pipe` in your angular with following logic.

```js
let ic = "020989-09-8990"
let c = ic.split("-")[0].match(/(..?)/g) // split the first part in pairs of two
console.log(c.join("/")) // join them finally
```

Answer (score 0):

Thus will show the date in the format that you want.

```
{{valueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pipe or component's method to represent these lines.

Note that Month in javascript is zero based.

```
var id = '01021988-XX-XXXX';
var dd = id.substr(0,2);
var mm = Number(id.substr(2,2)) - 1;
var yyyy = id.substr(4,4);
var date = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);
console.log(id, dd, mm, yyyy, date);
```